# Data disappears when element changes

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file containing details of events that I'm displaying on a calendar

If an event exits on that day, I append a div to the day on the calendar to show it has an event

The calendar I'm using is [VanillaCalendar](https://vanilla-calendar.pro/docs) and I init the calendar on DOM load and run my function to loop the JSON data and assign events to the days on the calendar

This is my loop to assign the events to the days:

```
        for (const {month, days} of eventData) {
          for (const {day, events} of days) {
              const key = day.split('-').map(p => p.padStart(2, '0')).join('-');
              let dayElement = document.querySelector(`[data-calendar-day="${key}"]`);
              let eventWrapper = document.createElement("div");
              eventWrapper.classList.add("event-wrapper");
              dayElement.append(eventWrapper);
              for (const {title, category} of events) {
                  let singleEvent = document.createElement("div");
                  singleEvent.classList.add("event", category);
                  eventWrapper.append(singleEvent);
              }
          }
```

You can see my [CodePen demo here](https://codepen.io/OnTheWeb/pen/gOZNzYz)

However when you change month the events don't populate on the calendar

If you see my [CodePen](https://stackoverflow.com) and change the month you'll see no events show for February even though there is data for February in the JSON data

If anyone can guide me on how to show the events even if it's a different month

I've tried using the [VanillaCalendar clickMonth action](https://vanilla-calendar.pro/docs/reference/additionally/actions#click-month) to run my function when the month arrows are clicked and added a delay like this but is still does not populate the events for February or any other month:

```
clickArrow(e, self) {
      setTimeout(assignEventsToCalendar, 3000);
}
```

Comment: `for (const entry of eventData)` this loop appears to be completely unnecessary since entry is not used.  It just causes all the code inside to execute n times.

Comment: @James ok thanks I can tidy that up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 things:

- assign event listener via options object, [docs](https://vanilla-calendar.pro/docs/reference/additionally/actions#click-arrow) - here we are assigning a named function rather than writing a new one so the assignment looks slightly different.
- removed superfluous loop over eventData
- only apply event flair if that day exists on the calendar.  Can just check if the element exists.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {   
    console.log(data.month);
    var currentDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);

    var options = {
        date: {
            min: "1920-01-01",
            max: "2038-12-31"
        },
        settings: {
            range: {
                min: currentDate
            },
            visibility: {
                disabled: true,
                theme: 'light'
            }
        },
        actions: {
          clickArrow: assignEventsToCalendar
        }
    };

    var calendar = new VanillaCalendar("#calendar", options);
    calendar.init();

    assignEventsToCalendar();

});

const assignEventsToCalendar = function() {
  let eventData = data;
  for (const {month, days} of eventData) {
    for (const {day, events} of days) {
      const key = day.split('-').map(p => p.padStart(2, '0')).join('-');
      let dayElement = document.querySelector(`[data-calendar-day="${key}"]`);
 
      if (dayElement) { // only apply flair if day exists (is in current month)
        let eventWrapper = document.createElement("div");
        eventWrapper.classList.add("event-wrapper");
        dayElement.append(eventWrapper);

        for (const {title, category} of events) {
          let singleEvent = document.createElement("div");
          singleEvent.classList.add("event", category);
          eventWrapper.append(singleEvent);
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution, you've answered what I was looking for. This makes sense to only check if element exists on the page. I think I've found more issues with my code or the calendar as the event markers also disappear when the day is clicked etc. so will need some extra thought